# When mapping ViewModel to Base Class automapper returns Sub Class

Tags: c#, polymorphism, automapper

This is my View Model class:

```
public class EntryViewModel { }
```

and in my code, depending on a certain parameter I'm trying to map it to:

base class:

```
public class Entry { }
```

or three sub classes:

```
public class VacationEntry : Entry { }

public class WorkEntry : Entry { }

public class SickLeaveEntry : Entry { }
```

Here are my created maps:

```
Mapper.CreateMap<Entry, EntryViewModel>(); 

Mapper.CreateMap<EntryViewModel, Entry>();

Mapper.CreateMap<EntryViewModel, VacationEntry >()
  .IncludeBase<EntryViewModel, Entry>();

Mapper.CreateMap<EntryViewModel, WorkEntry >()
  .IncludeBase<EntryViewModel, Entry>();

Mapper.CreateMap<EntryViewModel, SickLeaveEntry >()
  .IncludeBase<EntryViewModel, Entry>();

Mapper.AssertConfigurationIsValid();
```

Now when I'm mapping my View Model to Sub Class everything works fine - Mapper returns me class which I was expecting:

```
var entry = new EntryViewModel();
Entry result = Mapper.Map(entry, entry.GetType(), typeof(VacationEntry)) as Entry // result is type of VacationEntry
```

but when trying to map ViewModel to Base Class, my result is type of the last CreatedMap of Sub Classes - in this case SickLeaveEntry:

```
var entry = new EntryViewModel();
Entry result = Mapper.Map(entry, entry.GetType(), typeof(Entry)) as Entry // result is type of SickLeaveEntry, but I was expecting Entry
```

Is there any way to get base class from AutoMapper?

Comment: Maybe it should go without saying but I'm guessing you also initiate a mapper for Entry from EntryViewModel right? Mapper.CreateMap<Entry, EntryViewModel>()?

Comment: Yes, I also got this map: Mapper.CreateMap<Entry, EntryViewModel>();

Comment: Would you give it a try like that: Entry result = Mapper.Map<EntryViewModel, Entry>(entry). This is the way I use my automapper and I didn't have such a problem

Comment: I tried it in latest version of Automapper. It works as you want. What version do you use?

Comment: I was using version 4.0.4, but when I update to version 6.1.1 everything works fine. Thanks!